# How to make TV card item expandable when be selected and overlap to each other card in VerticalGridFragment

Tags: android, android-tv, leanback

I'm newbie on android TV application.

I had a question need some help to solve.
In `VerticalGridFragment` I had several card item to shown and 5 item in one row. I need the card info not to show if card doesn't selected. So I set `InfoVisibility method` of card presenter to **CARD_REGION_VISIBLE_SELECTED.**

```
cardView.setInfoVisibility(BaseCardView.CARD_REGION_VISIBLE_SELECTED);
```

Card info field is gone now. However, when card was selected. the Card Item below of selected Card display not exactly what I want. It position was changed.

### Here the screenshot:

[actual result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UzSPP.jpg)

[what I expect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vw8go.jpg)

Please help me to solve this problem. Thank you in advance.

Comment: An alternative solution is to use `cardView.setCardType(BaseCardView.CARD_TYPE_INFO_OVER);` method. Then the size of card don't change even if the card is selected (but in this case image will be overrided by card info).

Comment: I see. But I can't do that. I need card info is shown under card image in my case. Anyway, thanks for your help!

Comment: Did you solve the problem?
I also have the same problem as you.
Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

In my idea you can using create card_infor_layout in your card, when card focus change you can set Visiable. It's work for me. 
If youre Vietnamese add my skype : evanngo93@gmail.com